# Error: inject() must be called from an injection context

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, inject

I think I follow all the most liked solution on the web, but nothing do...
I have this issue `Error: inject() must be called from an injection context`

More than that, I have multiples warnings like 
`Warning: ###/src/app/app.module.ts depends on 'angularfire2/firestore'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts. For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies`

Because before installing and trying to use `npm install angularfire2 firebase --save` everythings was ok: no error and no warning...

So did anyone faced the same issue ?
I tried to add `projects.$name.architect.build.options.preserveSymlinks: true` in angular.json, or add `"paths": { "@angular/*": [ "../node_modules/@angular/*" ] }` in `tsconfig.app.json` under `compilerOptions` and others methods, but nothing save my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my issue by installing firebase dependencies with `ng add @angular/fire` and everything is ok, no error !